# Makefile Error in Matlab Real-Time Workshop

Tags: matlab, makefile, simulink, matlab-deployment

I'm using Real-Time Workshop to auto-generate executables for VxWorks, but I am getting an error at the following command:

```
J:\Tornado\tests\add\add_tornado_rtw>make -f add.mk  GENERATE_REPORT=0 TMW_EXTMODE_TESTING=0 RTWCAPIPARAMS=0 RTWCAPISIGNALS=0 MODELLIB=addlib.lib RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ANCHOR=.. MODELREF_TARGET_TYPE=NONE  
add.mk:345: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
### Real-Time Workshop build procedure for model: 'add' aborted due to an error.
```

Here is the makefile:
http://pastebin.com/m5bdf2c4c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your "make" is Cygwin's make, which does not allow native windows paths with colons in them:

```
MATLAB_ROOT         = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b
...
%.o : $(MATLAB_ROOT)/rtw/c/tornado/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(RT_MAIN_DEFINES) $<
```

This will expand to

```
%.o : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b/rtw/c/tornado/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(RT_MAIN_DEFINES) $<
```

i.e. make assumes that "C" is the pattern (which it doesn't find a % in).

Bugzilla report on the matter: https://chess.eecs.berkeley.edu/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55

You can download a patched version of make from here: http://www.cmake.org/files/cygwin/make.exe